# Is there a standard way to turn on and off a phone's flash light from a web browser?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, web, mobile-website

It appears [Firefox OS has a way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CameraControl) to turn a device's camera flash on and off.

Is there a way to turn the camera flash of a phone on or off in a standards-compliant way from within web browsers running on the phone? E.g. within Chrome on Android/iOS, Safari on iOS, etc.?

It appears you can [read the capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/CameraCapabilities) but not manually set them.

Asking to see if it's possible to build a [mobile webapp that works like a flashlight](https://github.com/WebUtils/Platform/issues/12).